# how to solve "Unable to resolve "@react-navigation/native-stack" from "App.js""

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-stack

I am new to react-native. I was running the programing but this problem kept coming.

I tried looking the solution all over the internet. Installed the react-navigation, react-navigation/native, react-navigation/native-stack but again the problem kept coming. I had even cleared the cache, quit and re-opened the program

Answer (score 0):

run this command in your root directory to install `@react-navigation/native-stack`

```
yarn add @react-navigation/native-stack
```